# can't detect objects in real time capture using a different coreml object

Tags: object-detection, coreml, coremltools

For recognizing object in live capture, I've downloaded the out-of-the-box project from the apple developers' site: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_objects_in_live_capture

The problem is that every other coreml I replace the ObjectDetector with, doesn't work - more specifically, I build the app on my phone but there are no 'boxes' showing me the objects being detected.
I've tried numerous models from https://coreml.store but none seem to work (although no errors are being thrown).

I'm guessing I'm missing a step and it's not just replacing the .mlmodel object and changing the name in

```
 guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ObjectDetector", withExtension: "mlmodelc")
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the models on that website are not "object detection" models but "classification" models. They return different kind of observation object, not the `VNRecognizedObjectObservation` objects the sample app looks for.

Comment: How can I control which kind of object is being returned?
I was following this document: https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/userguide/object_detection/

and after saving my trained model, I just import it into Xcode and try to use it.

Comment: A model is always trained for a specific purpose. Most free CoreML models are classifiers, so they only do that particular task. There are not a lot of free object detector models for Core ML / Vision available right now, since this capability was only added to Vision in iOS 12, which is still in beta. So unless whoever created this model explicitly tells you it can be used with Vision for object detection, it can't. If you want to train your own object detection model, right now all you can use is the Turi Create beta.

Comment: yes, that's what I did. I trained my own using Turi create beta. When it didn't work, I downloaded an example from that website, sort of to debug the problem. I understand that the model from the website isn't working because of the VNRecognizedObjectObservation object. I suspect this is also why my own trained model isn't working.
Is there anywhere in the process of training the model that I should explicitly define the object being returned?

Comment: What kind of model did you train using Turi Create?

Comment: I ran model = tc.object_detector.create(train_data) and I think it's defaulting to darknet-YOLO.

Comment: That ought to work as far as I understand it, but it's still in beta so who knows...